# MySQL data into template

Tags: php, mysql, templates

I'm starting with PHP and I have this code that works fine:

```
<body>

<?

require("conexaoBD.php");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tb_materia_prima";

$limite = mysql_query("$sql");

while ($sql = mysql_fetch_array($limite) ) {
    $data       = $sql["data"];
    $lote       = $sql["lote"];
    $material   = $sql["material"];
    $cor        = $sql["cor"];
    $quantidade = $sql["quantidade"];
    $prazo      = $sql["prazo"];

    echo "<div id=\"testeID\">
            Data: $data<br> Lote: $lote<br> Material: $material<br> Cor: $cor<br> Quantidade: $quantidade Kilos<br> Previsão de entrega: $prazo<br><a href=\"#\">Editar</a>
          </div>";
}

?>

</body>
```

But, now I wanna put the echo data into the HTML like this:

```
<div>

Data: <p><?php echo $data ?></p>
<br /><br />
Lote: <p><?php echo $lote ?></p>
<br /><br />
Material: <p><?php echo $material ?></p>
<br /><br />
Cor: <p><?php echo $cor ?></p>
<br /><br />
Quantidade: <p><?php echo $quantidade ?></p>
<br /><br />
Prazo: <p><?php echo $prazo ?></p>

</div>
```

It works fine too, but just return the last MySQL entry. How do I show all the entries?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get your data first, and then start for HTML template

```
<?php
require("conexaoBD.php");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tb_materia_prima";
$limite = mysql_query($sql);
$data = array();
while ($sql = mysql_fetch_array($limite) ) {
    $data[] = $sql;
}
?>
<body>
<?php foreach ($data as $row): ?>
    <div id="testeID">
        Data:                <?=$row['data']?><br> 
        Lote:                <?=$row['lote']?><br> 
        Material:            <?=$row['material']?><br>
        Cor:                 <?=$row['cor']?><br> 
        Quantidade:          <?=$row['quantidade']?> Kilos<br> 
        Previsão de entrega: <?=$row['prazo']?><br>
        <a href="#">Editar</a>
    </div>
<?php endforeach ?>
</body>
```

However, it's better to get your data using [PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info):

```
<?php
require("conexaoBD.php");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tb_materia_prima";
$stm = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stm->execute();
$data = $stm->fetchAll();
?>
```

of course, the template part will remain the same. **That's the very point of the templates**: while changing your program logic, your template will remain the same. The opposite is true as well